# How to solve " ValueError: Element count of value (1) doesn\'t match type_definition (2)" when I teleport ksm in kusama to ksm in statemine?

Tags: kusama, xcm, python, substrateinterface, statemine

I want to teleport the ksm in kusama to ksm in statemine. I use the code

```
call = _substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='XcmPallet',
        call_function='limited_teleport_assets',
        call_params={
            'dest':
                {"V1": {
                    "parents": 0,
                    "interior": {"X1": {"Parachain": 1000}}
                }},
            "beneficiary":
                {"V1": {
                    "parents": 0,
                    "interior":
                        {"X1": {
                            "AccountId32": {"network": "Any",
                                            "id": target}}}}},
            "assets": {"V1": [
                                {"id": {"Concrete": {"parents": 0,
                                                     "interior": "Here"
                                                     }}},
                                {"fun": {"Fungible": amount}}
                            ]},
            "fee_asset_item": 0,
            "weight_limit": "Unlimited",
        }
    )
```

but the error is
`{"code": -32000, "message": "Server error", "data": "ValueError: Element count of value (1) doesn\'t match type_definition (2)"}`

Comment: It help a little. But the error still is "ValueError: Element count of value (1) doesn't match type_definition (2)"

Comment: The idea is to first query the endpoint and check out the data formats. Did you use what the answer suggested to query?

Comment: "substrate.get_metadata_call_function("XcmPallet","LimitedTeleportAssets")"  and "substrate.get_metadata_storage_function("XcmPallet","LimitedTeleportAssets")" return None. None object cant' get the format

Comment: Maybe because `limited_teleport_assets` is a call function and it's named as such?
https://kusama.subscan.io/runtime/XcmPallet?version=9170

Comment: I have tried it so many conbinations.But they return None